# Jssor slider bullet navigator does not positioning in the middle in IE

Tags: jssor

Jssor slider bullet navigator does not positioning in the middle in IE 10, it is fine with the other browsers. Here is the url: http://kvarkcleaning-bg.4stupki.com/.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your css as below,

```
div#header div.content div.headers {
    margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; width: 900px; height: 250px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px;
}
div#header div.content div#headers div.slides {
    width: 900px; height: 250px; cursor: move; overflow: hidden;
}
```

and change the 'slider container' html as below,

```
<div id="headers" class="headers">
```

Note that it's necessary to always specify 'top', 'left' for 'slider container'. And always specify 'overflow: hidden' for 'slides' container.